# android studio intent in startActivities error

Tags: android-intent

I'm trying to create intent, but I have hard. I used two methods, I ended the same result in main java.

`startactivities(android.content.intent[]` in activity can not be applied.
could please help me

Comment: Please provide some code. Provide the methods you have used and information needed to answer your question. Please clarify what's your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot Amir, I sorted out

Answer (score 0):

use 'startActivity(new Intent(yourActivityName.this, NextActivity.class));'
this example is of explicit intent.